# InApp getSkuDetails producing ANRs

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, android-anr-dialog

For a game with couple of million active users, I am using InApp Billing V3 and calls getSkuDetails to load the prices of my in app items.

I do call getSkuDetails from a separate thread and still ِANRs keeps taking place.

Did anyone face similar ANRs? or Am I doing something wrong ?

And here is the ANR stack:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x73f81268 self=0xa7f85400
  | sysTid=16197 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaac0e534
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=124 stm=29 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe73e000-0xbe740000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 0000000000048618  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 000000000001adef  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+38)
  #02  pc 000000000003c1bb  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+170)
  #03  pc 000000000003caf3  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState15waitForResponseEPNS_6ParcelEPi+238)
  #04  pc 0000000000035f11  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android8BpBinder8transactEjRKNS_6ParcelEPS1_j+36)
  #05  pc 00000000000959a1  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
  #06  pc 00000000005e9bf1  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_BinderProxy_transactNative__ILandroid_os_Parcel_2Landroid_os_Parcel_2I+140)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (BinderProxy.java)
  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact (BinderProxy.java:641)
  at com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.getSkuDetails (IInAppBillingService.java:370)
  at com.mygame.mygame.GameActivity.lambda$getRemoveAdsPrice$2$GameActivity (GameActivity.java:759)
  at com.mygame.mygame.GameActivity$$Lambda$2.run (GameActivity.java)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6153)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:865)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution? My apps has the same anr